# Sk-Maps animate to location is not centering correctly

Tags: android, skmaps

I am using SK Maps. I can display annotation on Location but the map doesn't get centered to that location but it gets centered to some different location and the `animateToZoom` doesn't zoom smoothly. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed in the latest build 3.0.1. Please use the new build from here: http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7827-Android-3-0-1-release-candidate-build

Comment: The problem still not solved.I have added the 3.0.1 build by downloading from above link, but no improvement.

Comment: Please sens an email to dev@telenav.com with the issue reproduced in the demo app.

Comment: @SylviA this issue seems to indeed be fixed by 3.0.1 (was broken on 3.0.0), however I still have issues with something else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868066/issues-with-skmaps-with-certain-devices

Comment: @HaydenKai thanks for the update- for the second question someone from the support team would help you