# Issues with SKMaps with certain devices

Tags: android, skmaps

I have found two issues with `SKMaps 3.0.0` with two of my Android devices, although they seem to not be issues on other devices (such as my tablet).

Devices include: 
`Samsung S6 Edge+ Android:6.0.1`
`Nexus 6 Android:5.1.1`

1. `EDIT:STILL BROKEN WITH 3.0.1` `SKPolyline.setOutlineSize()` seems to have a maximum size around 10. Setting it any higher does not affect the line size. I reported this to the skobbler team already and nothing has been done about it.
2. `EDIT:FIXED WITH 3.0.1` `SKMapSurfaceView.animateToLocation()` seems to animate the location to the location to the bottom of the map, so that the center of the map is exactly half way above the spot I would have liked to animate to. Sometimes it works correctly, but this is rare.

If anyone has encountered these issues and has solutions please let me know...

Answer (score 3):

The issued has been fixed with in our 3.0.2 release, now the line width and the outline width of the polyline can be set to any value between 0 and 100.
You can find the links for the 3.0.2 release candidate builds in our forum:
http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/14515-3-0-2-release-candidate-builds

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first problem reported, it seems there's a bug in the SDK. Our dev team is handling the issue. The feature will be available in a future version of our SDK.